# 2 different on click events conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="lorem hello"> link </a>
```

And I have two different onclick function set to the two classes like this:

```
jQuery(".lorem").each(function(){
    this.onclick = function() {

        // stuff

    }
});
```

and

```
jQuery(".hello").each(function(){
    this.onclick = function() {

        // stuff

    }
});
```

This stops the top one to work. Why? And how can I make both functions work while being separated?

Comment: jQuery and  `onclick` handlers? You are doing something anti-pattern. Use the jQuery `on` method for binding event handlers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only assign one function to the `onclick` property. You should use normal jQuery event binding, it allows multiple handlers:

```
$(".lorem").click(function() {
    // stuff
});
$(".hello").click(function() {
    // stuff
});
```

If you want to do it with native Javascript, you can use `addEventListener`; as the name suggests, these are additive, they don't replace.

```
jQuery(".lorem").each(function(){
    this.addEventListener("click", function() {

        // stuff

    })
});
jQuery(".hello").each(function(){
    this.addEventListener("click", function() {

        // stuff

    })
});
```

Answer (score 5):

When you are using query, why use `.onclick` on the DOM element (therefore overwriting the previous binding). Instead use jQuery's `.on`:

```
$('.lorem').on('click', function(){
  // something
});
$('.hello').on('click', function(){
  // something else
});
```